# Rails 4 Development Image Won't Appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm running Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4.2.2, RVM, Development Mode.

I bought this Twitter Bootstrap template off Wrapbootstrap.com, https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/stamp-responsive-startup-theme-WB0M409X7
and I'm using this version of it, Home Style Two
http://templateocean.com/stamp/image-bg/2-home-style-two/index.html
I put all the images in the assets/images folder, then all the rest of the css and js and html files in the vender folder.

I can't get the background image to appear. I can get all other images to appear, just not this background one. The reference is in styles.css, line 497

```
.header {
background: url(../images/background-images/1.jpg) no-repeat center top       fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

I have tried changing styles.css to styles.css.scss and also to styles.scss. Then I have tried changing the code to the following:

```
 background: image-url('background-images/background.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
```

It's madness. Any ideas?

Comment: did you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: yes but that shouldn't make a difference in development mode, should it?

Comment: You have put all the images in assets/images folder? then see my answer. let me know if it worked

Comment: The image was already in assets/images folder. I ran the compile again. It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the lame things. I was looking for the needle in the haystack and it was the haystack all along. I did not have a closing  tag. And that was creating all the trouble.